# How to run useEffect (and a cloud firestore query) only when object is defined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

trying to only run a firestore 'onSnapshot' when the 'user' is defined. At first, user is an empty object, and later it becomes an object with id, name, etc. So this shouldn't run... But it seems that this 'if' statement is not working (the firestore onSnapshot will run even if it is undefined).

How to fix this?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) { //object is undefined at first, but gets defined later
      const unsubscribe = firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user.id) //This seems to run even when 'user' is undefined (an empty object)
        .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
           //...
        })

      return () => {
        unsubscribe()
      }
    }
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include `user` as a dependency in your useEffect hook

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      //object is undefined at first, but gets defined later
      const unsubscribe = firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("users")
        .doc(user.id) //This seems to run even when 'user' is undefined (an empty object)
        .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
          //...
        });

      return () => {
        unsubscribe();
      };
    }
  }, [user]);
```